# Deploying Golang app with Bower on Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, go, bower

I have a bower.json file in my root directory, but it doesn't run "bower install." Otherwise my Go app works, but without Bootstrap and other dependencies. But when I add a package.json file and format it correctly, Heroku incorrectly tries to deploy my app as a Node.js app and fails. Is it possible to get Golang and Bower to play nice on a Heroku deployment?

Comment: The Go build pack for Heroku won't read or run a package.json or bower.json - you should run them before you do a `git push` to Heroku, and/or as part of a commit hook that rebuilds the assets - either should put them into a static/ or dist/ directory that your Go application then serves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use several buildpacks in your app:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go.git
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
```

Once these two commands are executed, your app will first be compiled as a Go one, then as a Node one.
Your Go app will then be compiled and launchable. Your npm dependencies will also be installed, and the script command in `package.json` be executable allowing you to install bower dependencies.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app
And https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process

Comment: After adding this nodejs buildpack, I also had to add bower to package.json as a dependency. Then instead of pointing the `Procfile` to the Go binary, I pointed it to a Bash script which would call `bower install` if the directory set in `.bowerrc` did not exist (e.g., "bower_components"). Afterwards, the Bash script called the Go binary. So it looked like `[ -d "bower_components" ] || bower install; server/bin/serve;`

Comment: Adding `bower install` as a post install script (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#hook-things-up) would be better, as it would compile your scripts at deploy time, not boot time. That would speed up boot time, which has a 60 seconds timeout (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#boot-timeout).